# Need help fixing error code on html validaitor

Tags: html

I need help to fix my errors. I am a beginner at HTML so don’t know much.

[image: Errors]

Comment: The warnings and errors seem pretty clear in what they are telling you. Perhaps you could clarify what exactly your issue is.. "The X role is unnecessary for element Y" would suggest that you just need to remove the role because it is unnecessary. Likewise type is not allowed for a p so remove the type attribute. These seem pretty obvious so I am assuming your question is something more than just how to get rid of the warnings/errors here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in setting a `role` for an element if the type of the element is intrinsically of that role in the first place.

e.g. `<nav>` elements are for navigation, so saying `<nav role="navigation">` is just repeating yourself. So don't. Just say `<nav>`.

---

`<p>` elements don't have `type` attributes. You *might* be looking for `role` again, but if you want a button, use a `<button>`. Paragraphs are not buttons, so if you want a button, don't use a `<p>`.